# Selecting and Listing Distinct

Tags: sql-server

I am having a problem selecting a buyers name, products they bought, and price of items. I want the results to just show the buyers name once and list every product/price of said product.

```
Select distinct Buyer_First_Name, Buyer_Last_Name, Appliance_num, Price
    from Buyer inner join Appliance
    on buyer.Buyer_num = Appliance.Buyer_num;
```

This winds up listing the buyers name multiple times, as it is selecting all of the items distinct. The results I am seeing with this code is:

```
Buyer_First_Name   Buyer_First_Name     Appliance_num    Price
John               Smith                000001           $19.99
John               Smith                000002           $45.99
John               Smith                000003           $12.99
John               Smith                000004           $17.99
Mike               Brown                000001           $19.99
Mike               Brown                000005           $33.99
Mike               Brown                000006           $29.99
```

What I want to see:

```
Buyer_First_Name   Buyer_First_Name     Appliance_num    Price
John               Smith                000001           $19.99
                                        000002           $45.99
                                        000003           $12.99
                                        000004           $17.99
Mike               Brown                000001           $19.99
                                        000005           $33.99
                                        000006           $29.99
```

Thanks.

Comment: What reporting tool are you using?

Comment: SQL Server isn't designed to do this type of thing. You'll need to handle this in whatever you are using to present the data.

Answer (score 2):

Hiding the duplicates is something you need to do in the presentation, not in the query.  Look for an option in your reporting tool or adjust your code to do this.